# Best way to animate visiblity of UICollectionViewCell in iOS7+

Tags: ios7, uicollectionviewcell, uiviewanimation, alpha

I need to animate the visibility of UICollectionViewCells on startup such that they are visible randomly when my application launches. But since I already have the items to be displayed they are visible at the same time. I tried below solution & it works correctly. But I want to know the best & optimized way to achieve this task

```
- (void)animateCollectionViewCellsVisiblity
{
    // First set alpha to 0
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i< self.dataArray.count; i++)
    {
        [self applyAlpha:0.0 toItem:i inSection:0];
    }

    // Initially collectionview is hidden while fetching data, so show it now
    self.collectionView.hidden = NO;

    // Now set alpha to 1 with a random delay
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i< self.dataArray.count; i++)
    {
        CGFloat delay = [self randomNumberWithlowerBound:0 upperBound:self.dataArray.count] + 0.05;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            [self applyAlpha:1.0 toItem:i inSection:0];
        } completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)applyAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha toItem:(NSInteger)item inSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = (MyCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section]];
    cell.alpha = alpha;
}

- (int)randomNumberWithlowerBound:(int)lowerBound upperBound:(int)upperBound
{
    int randomValue = arc4random_uniform(upperBound - lowerBound + 1) + lowerBound;
    return randomValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is great. That's how it is done. Looks pretty optimized to me.

You could make your code shorter by dropping the `section` parameter which is always zero. And you possibly eliminate the `applyAlpha` method by adding just two lines before your animate block.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I agree with you for removing the applyAlpha method.